# DJI Inspire 1 v2.0 Laptop Control

Tags: dji-phantom

What are the options available to allow someone to control a DJI Inspire 1 v2.0 using an application installed on a Windows laptop?

I know there are dongles available, but I'm not certain which are the best options or would be compatible with that platform.

Comment: Do you mean an RC control link USB dongle for your computer?

Comment: @ifconfig Wow, so how about that for being exhausted. I have a few questions about DJI kit being asked on this Stack Exchange. For whatever reason I thought you had responded to one of my other ones. Sorry about that. YES, exactly what you said. A dongle which allows me to control the drone using applications on my PC, thanks! I'll delete my previous to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Ah, okay. :) Understood. Could you still please edit your question to say something like that?